# jquery parse text within braces

Tags: jquery, regex, parsing

I want to remove

- the entire text including curly braces
- the outer braces, but not the text within [[ and ]] only

[[Have to keep this text]] this {{ remove this junk }} and this.

I implemented the above and it is working at : http://jsfiddle.net/DMGdG/
I used this : https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-replacetext/master/jquery.ba-replacetext.min.js

but in my server(127.0.0.1) the same code is not doing the trick, there i tried both the ways

```
str.replace(regex, charecter)
```

and the one mentioned at jsfiddle.

My queries:

- is my regex combo correct, if not please suggest, what is wrong.
- Please don't think of any server error at its simply a main.js

```
jstr.replace("/\s*\{{.*?\}}\s*/g", " "); // for removing curly braces and text within.

jstr.replace("/[\[(.)\]]/g", ""); // to replace the square braces.
```

index.html has only a `<p> Sample Text(as shown above)</p>`

Comment: What happens when the text is this `[[Have to keep this text]]] this {{{ remove this junk }} and this.` or `this {{ remove this [[Have to keep this text]] junk }} and this.` ?

Comment: that is not included in the test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$("p").replaceText(/\{\{.+\}\}/U/gi, '****' );
```

Try this:

```
$("p").replaceText(/\{\{.+?\}\}/gi, '****' );
```

The addition of the question mark makes the matched pattern non-greedy -- that is, it will match the very next `}}` it encounters, rather the the very last one.

---

Edit: You've stated this doesn't work for you. Perhaps omitting the replaceText plug-in and using plain old `replace()` instead will help:

```
$("p").each( function(){
    $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/\{\{.+?\}\}/gi, '****' ) );
});
```

Again, it seems to work in your fiddle when edited as above. Perhaps the problem is with the plug-in.

Comment: it does not work probably because the text that i am sending in jscript string object has aproxly 7000 words. Let me know your thots on using the above method with such a long string.

Comment: @Rahul, the above suggestion does work (at least for me) when I blow up the paragraph to 7000 words. Then again, if you have really big datasets to process, perhaps you should look at doing more work server-side.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(function()
{
    $("p").replaceText(/\{\{.*?\}\}/gi, '' ); //removes {{...}}
    $("p").replaceText(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/gi, '$1' ); //removes [[ and ]] around text
});
```